# How to format and regulate indentations in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm creating a whole bunch of JSON files pieced together from other generated JSON. Some of this generated JSON has 1 space indents/tabs, some have 2 space indents/tabs, some have 4 space indent/tabs.

Is there a way I can select several lines of code and have all the indents formatted to my default?

I've tried various beautify plugins but they don't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Format Document" command which should respect your `.editorconfig` if you have any.

[image]